# trying to overload function, however Xcode display error

Tags: xcode, swift, function, overloading

I'm trying to build a calculator using Swift. Below is the code I have came up with.

For these switch cases:

```
case "×":performOperation {$0 * $1}
case "÷":performOperation {$1 / $0}
case "+":performOperation {$0 + $1}
case "−":performOperation {$1 - $0}
```

It accepts a two arguments function:

```
func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double){
    if operandStack.count >= 2{
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}
```

For this switch case:

```
case "√":performOperation {sqrt($0)}
```

I have came up with an overloading function that only accept one argument:

```
func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){
    if operandStack.count >= 1{
        displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
        enter()
    }
}
```

However, the Xcode has an error displayed next to the one argument function, saying:

> Method "performOperation" with Objective-C selector "performOperation"
>   conflicts with previous declaration wiht the same Objective C selector

This is causing a great deal of confusion for me. First, I'm using Swift, so why Objective C? Second, how can I solve a problem like this? Please help me!!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            enter()
        }
        switch operation {
        case "×":performOperation {$0 * $1}
        case "÷":performOperation {$1 / $0}
        case "+":performOperation {$0 + $1}
        case "−":performOperation {$1 - $0}
        case "√":performOperation {sqrt($0)}
        default: break
        }

    }

    func performOperation(operation: (Double, Double) -> Double){
        if operandStack.count >= 2{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast(), operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }

    func performOperation(operation: Double -> Double){
        if operandStack.count >= 1{
            displayValue = operation(operandStack.removeLast())
            enter()
        }
    }

    var operandStack = Array<Double>()

    @IBAction func enter() {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)
        print("operantStack = \(operandStack)")
    }

    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController inherits from an Objective C type (UIViewController) - even though you only use swift. If you created a swift only file, you would find you can use method name overloads as you have done. So one of your performOperation needs to change.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. Do you mind if I ask a follow up question? Please correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of what you said is if the file only contain Swift code, then I can use method name overload, but because I am using UIViewController, which is a type inherited from an Object C type, therefore I can't use method name overload and have to name give those methods different names, is this correct? Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I should add that when I say a Swift file I meant a Swift class or struct. And in the case of a Swift class, it does not inherit from an Objective C type.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! god bless you!